# Doubleclick event in datefield - extjs 4.2.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, double-click, datefield

I am trying to fill a datefield with todays date by doubleclicking the datefield.
now I have no clickevent for xtype: datefield.

is it possible to still 'add' a doubleclick event to a datefield, or is there another workaround??

example code:

```
xtype: 'datefield',
name: 'reminderDate',
itemId: 'reminderDate',
fieldLabel: 'Erinnerung am',
padding: '10',
style: 'background-color: red'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Ext.form.field.Date`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date) does not have `dblclick` event. However after component is rendered you can bind listener for `dblclick` event on datefield input element. You can get datefield input element from `Ext.form.field.Date` [`inputEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-property-inputEl) property.

```
xtype: 'datefield',
fieldLabel: 'Date',
name: 'date',
listeners: { 
    afterrender: function(c) {
        c.inputEl.on('dblclick', function(){
            c.setValue(new Date());
        });
    }
}
```

Live fiddle with example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2bo

Comment: doesn't seem to work. When I put an alert in the afterrender, it won't display it either. Could it be that the afterrender event don't get called?

Comment: `afterrender` is fired when component has been completely rendered. Look at this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2bo

Comment: Yes seems to be right. thank you. i guess my problem is that my component doesnt render completely. I'll check on that.